# Install Ubuntu on Intel Mac

Tags: dual-boot, mac, apple

I've recently taken up a position in an all Mac workshop - We have Intel based Apple machines. Can I dual boot Ubuntu on my machine, if so how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Mactel Support Team maintains a [support matrix](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/CommunityHelpPages) that catalogs instructions for installing and configuring Ubuntu on specific Mac hardware releases.

Dual booting is accomplished using [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: It's not that hard to do actually, given your mac is not too old (my mac mini from 2009 works just fine). It's even got better in Natty, where I didn't have to do any tweaking to get the hardware to work ; actually everything (audio, nvidia video card, etc.) worked out of the box (you just have to install the proprietary drivers, of course). That being said, I wouldn't recommend that option to everyone, it's still a bit harder to install than on a standard PC.

Comment: Is it normal that the boot takes so long? First rEfit, then Grub, then *black screen* for some time then boot splash, then login screen...