# I have successfully burned ubuntu (correctly) but my mac wont boot up from the cd

Tags: live-cd, mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Ubuntu on Intel Mac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16604/install-ubuntu-on-intel-mac)

I have successfully burned ubuntu (correctly) on to a blank cd and I'm trying to try it out on my mac now. But when I restart it just boots up with the normal mac operating system. help?

Comment: holding down 'C' while booting is the usual way to boot from cd media                                                          or- hold down Options-Command-Shift-Delete to make it bypass the normal boot device and make it search for another.