# How can I install Ubuntu on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: mac

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install Ubuntu on Intel Mac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16604/install-ubuntu-on-intel-mac)

I would like to install Ubuntu in a Mac with OS X Lion. Can anyone tell me how it can be done?
Thx.
O.

Answer (score 1):

See if your system is supported in the Mactel support matrix...

[Support Matrix](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/CommunityHelpPages)