# Install Mac Os X on Ubuntu (dual boot)

Tags: dual-boot, mac

I have a computer running ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I downloaded the dmg file of a Mac OS X version.
Can I install it in dual boot with ubuntu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Ubuntu on Intel Mac](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16604/install-ubuntu-on-intel-mac)

Comment: Where did you download a dmg? I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my 2007 iMac using an iso. I have a triple boot using OS X 10.10.3, Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu. The Ubuntu install was in EFI/GPT mode. Seems to work fine so far. I can switch operating systems by using rEFInd. If you have any questions beyond this one, please ask.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a virtual machine to run OSX as an 'application' inside Ubuntu; VirtualBox (it's in the repos) is probably your best bet to do this. As far as dual-booting goes, it can be done, but it's usually a tricky process and requires specific hardware.

Note that you'll usually need an "ISO" image file to install OSX using either method, rather than a "DMG", which is a filetype that is (to my knowledge) only widely used on OSX. I'm not sure whether Apple provides images in this format.

Comment: I know, I used dmg2img... But are you sure that I can't install it with ubuntu?