# Ubuntu wont dual-boot on a mac

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation

Im using a VIN, iMac (21.5-inch Mid 2010) and trying to dual-boot ubuntu on it.  Whenever I put the .iso file onto a flashdrive with unetbootin, then restart my mac, hold alt, and click on the orange disk, it brings up the try without installing, download ubuntu... page, but when I press enter over any of them, It looks like something starts to run, but then my screen goes black, and about 10 seconds later I hear this sound like some one beats a bongo 3 times fast (not kidding).  Ive have partitioned away 80 GB of space for it as well.  I know its not the .iso file, because it runs perfectly fine on Virtualbox, just a little slow.  Any help is areciated, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Ubuntu on Intel Mac](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16604/install-ubuntu-on-intel-mac)

Comment: That bongo sound is a normal one from Ubuntu itself, which indicates to me that it's (partially) booting correctly, but perhaps there's a graphics driver issue. Have you tried selecting the "nomodeset" boot option? I believe you can view the options, and select `nomodeset`, by pressing F6 at the "Try Ubuntu/Install Ubuntu" screen.

Comment: F6 doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using Apple's Bootcamp (you can get this off the Mac Appstore)
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/CommunityHelpPages Here is a link to the Ubuntu page which tells you what is compatible.

Comment: My model (iMac 11,2) isn't on the list.